# How to configure rsyslog to use the imfile module?

Tags: rsyslog

I have Red Hat 9.2 with rsyslog v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1.

I use default /etc/rsyslog.conf and a custom configuration called `vums.conf` located in /etc/rsyslog.d/.

```
module(load="imfile")
input(type="imfile"
      File="/opt/wildfly/standalone/log/server.log"
      Tag="wildfly")
```

When I restart the rsyslog I see the following error when I run `systemctl status rsyslog`:

```
[root@konor2 rsyslog.d]# systemctl status rsyslog
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-12-20 07:32:55 CET; 1s ago
       Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
             https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
   Main PID: 574855 (rsyslogd)
      Tasks: 4 (limit: 36037)
     Memory: 1.4M
        CPU: 23ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
             └─574855 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n

Dec 20 07:32:55 konor2 systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Dec 20 07:32:55 konor2 rsyslogd[574855]: module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added  [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2221 ]
Dec 20 07:32:55 konor2 rsyslogd[574855]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1" x-pid="574855" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Dec 20 07:32:55 konor2 systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Dec 20 07:32:55 konor2 rsyslogd[574855]: imjournal: journal files changed, reloading...  [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

The error tells me that "*module 'imfile' already in this config, cannot be added*". In case I comment the `module(load="imfile")` line I receive the following error:

```
[root@konor2 rsyslog.d]# systemctl status rsyslog
● rsyslog.service - System Logging Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rsyslog.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-12-20 07:34:54 CET; 1s ago
       Docs: man:rsyslogd(8)
             https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/
   Main PID: 576081 (rsyslogd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 36037)
     Memory: 5.1M
        CPU: 23ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/rsyslog.service
             └─576081 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n

Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 systemd[1]: Starting System Logging Service...
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: input module name 'imfile' is unknown [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2209 ]
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 systemd[1]: Started System Logging Service.
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/vums.conf, on or before line 13: parameter 'Tag' not known -- typo in config file? [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https:>
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/vums.conf, on or before line 13: parameter 'File' not known -- typo in config file? [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https>
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: input module name 'imfile' is unknown [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/2209 ]
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/vums.conf, on or before line 13: parameter 'Tag' not known -- typo in config file? [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https:>
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: error during parsing file /etc/rsyslog.d/vums.conf, on or before line 13: parameter 'File' not known -- typo in config file? [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https>
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1" x-pid="576081" x-info="https://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Dec 20 07:34:54 konor2 rsyslogd[576081]: imjournal: journal files changed, reloading...  [v8.2102.0-113.el9_2.1 try https://www.rsyslog.com/e/0 ]
```

The error tells that "*input module name 'imfile' is unknown*".

How to configure rsyslog to be able to use the imfile module and the input definition without the errors above?

Comment: Unix & Linux or Server Fault might be a better fit for your question.

Comment: Re first error I would grep the config to very that you only have that one instance of module load.  Your 2nd test suggest that is the case.  The other option then is that your conf file is being loaded multiple times?  Maybe old instance vs new instance of the process but you said you did a restart so doesn't sound right.  Maybe do stop, verify it's down, then start just to be sure?

Comment: @AllanWind Thank you for your answer.
ad 1) Only one instance running: I tried to perform systemctl stop checked the process is down and then systemctl start. The result is the same.
ad 2) As far as I know, there are only 2 config files used. Both I mentioned above. The imfile module is not mentioned anywhere except the lines I added.

I will try the Server Fault. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I never used rsyslog... do you by any chance include your config file, and it's automatically included (by virtue for name and/or path), too?  The other silly thing to check is that your editor didn't create a temp file (`find . -ls`)

Comment: The additional files are loaded with this option:

# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
include(file="/etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf" mode="optional")

I don't see any temp files in the /etc/ and /etc/rsyslog.d/ directory.